# Several AsyncTasks in Service

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service which can be called from Activities in an app.

The service contains of two different AsyncTasks that downloads data and populates a DB. The tasks downloads different data, and the operations may take some time. 
So I want to prevent the Tasks from being run simultaneously, but if one task is running I would like to queue the second task.

This could happen if the users switch activity before the task is completed.

How can this be done? Can I sleep the second task in some way?
Hope this is understandable :)

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) be more appropriate? You can fire tasks at it, and it'll execute them one at a time in a single background thread.

If you need to get results back from these operations, you can use a `BroadcastReceiver` to capture messages from the service.

Comment: Can I in some way have this service to auto refresh. Calling a method that executes a AsyncTask in a given interval? Send a broadcast to itself seems like a ugly solution...